# Natural logarithm cannot be computed in Delphi const at compile time

Tags: delphi, compile-time-constant, natural-logarithm

As I understand a thumb rule for allowing expressions in *Delphi* constants is that the expression should be able to get evaluated in complile time.

So it's greatly unclear for me why the following is not allowed *([dcc64 Error] E2026 Constant expression expected):*

```
const    
  SCAPEGOATALHPA = 2.0 / 3;
  SCAPEGOATCONST = 1.0 / ln(SCAPEGOATALHPA);
```

Is something that would prevent Delphi compute the natural logarithm of a constant float number? Or just a Delphi bug, as usual?

Comment: The reason is that `Ln` is a normal function, just like one you'd write yourself. Hence it can only be executed at runtime. If you Ctrl-click `Ln`, you will see its source code. The same thing applies to `Sqrt`, for instance. But if you ctrl-click `Rount`, you will not see its source code. That's because that is a "magic" function, and it can be used at compile time.

Comment: In the end you can only combine literals - and `ln()` is a function with a result, not a literal. Don't confuse this with typecasting, which looks the same (i.e. `Double(5)`) and still is a literal.

Comment: `Double(5)` isn't a literal, but it is still a constant expression.

Comment: `high` is also accepted: `const XXX = high(integer);` Though `high` is also a normal function, in system unit. So I still cannot see lots of logic in that.

Comment: Though you're right, `high` has indeed no source code.

Comment: @ZoltánBíró: No, `High` is not a normal function. If you ctrl-click it, you are not taken to its source code.

Comment: Not a bug, just that the language designers didn't choose to support such things

Comment: The docs explicitly  list the available functions: Abs, High, Low, Pred, Succ, Chr, Length. Odd, Round, Swap, Hi, Lo, Ord, SizeOf, Trunc: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Declared_Constants#Constant_Expressions