# Delphi Compilation Error "Constant expression expected" for const initialization

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to translate some Java code to Delphi and encountered an issue when defining constants inside a class. Here's the code snippet:

```
TALSplineOverScroller = class(TObject)
private
  const INFLEXION: Single = 0.35;
  const START_TENSION: Single = 0.5;
  const P1: Single = TALSplineOverScroller.START_TENSION * TALSplineOverScroller.INFLEXION;
end;
```

When I try to compile this, I get the error:

> E2026 Constant expression expected

on the line where P1 is declared. Why is this happening and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Duplicate of e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72318716/natural-logarithm-cannot-be-computed-in-delphi-const-at-compile-time (cannot flag as such because no approved answer)

Comment: @JanDoggen: There are significant differences between these Qs IMHO.

Comment: Bonus questions: is it really a _declaration_ or just a _definition_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, please note that your question doesn't contain a *minimal* example of the issue.

The class is a red herring.

The following is a better example:

```pascal
const
  INFLEXION: Single = 0.35;
  START_TENSION: Single = 0.5;
  P1: Single = START_TENSION * INFLEXION;
```

But it is still not minimal. The following example is what you should have posted (in a "perfect" question):

```pascal
const
  a: Single = 0.1;
  b = 10 * a;
```

Now, let me answer *this* question, i.e. why this doesn't compile!

As it often is, the answer is found in the documentation.

The documentation for the [E2026](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/E2026_Constant_expression_expected_(Delphi)) exception says:

> The compiler expected a constant expression here, but the expression it found turned out not to be constant.

Now, what's a "constant expression"? Well, head over to [Declared Constants](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants):

> Declared constants are either *true constants* or *typed constants*. These two kinds of constant are superficially similar, but they are governed by different rules and used for different purposes.
>
> [...]
>
> Typed constants, unlike true constants, can hold values of array, record, procedural, and pointer types. Typed constants cannot occur in constant expressions.

So, by design, you cannot use a typed constant in a constant expression.

One obvious workaround is to use a true constant instead of a typed constant:

```pascal
const
  a = 0.1;
  b = 10 * a;
```

If this is acceptable in your case, I don't know. This will, for instance, change `SizeOf(a)`.

Comment: perfect answer, i was not aware that their is a difference between "type" constante, thanks

Comment: @zeus There's also a difference between [their](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/their) and [there](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/their).

Comment: @AmigoJack Ah, the classic their/there dilemma strikes again. Thanks for pointing it out!